# assigning a value in an arraylist to a int in another class

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I am very new to java, and I'm currently in the process of writing a java code for a student record system.
I have made a class that asks the user to enter the year the student has completed, as seen here

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentYear 
{
    public void StudentYear()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> studentYear = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter the year the student has most recently completed: ");
        studentYear.add(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println(studentYear);
        }
    }
```

I would now like to define a new int in a new class, int year = (year the student entered in above code to arraylist), so i can use their year value elsewhere.
How would i go about using the 1st stored value of the arraylist 'studentYear' in another class and assigning it to a 'int year'?

Hope that is clear, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are only taking in one value, why use the `ArrayList`?  But in any case, you would define the constructor of your other class to take an int as a parameter, or you could have a setter method in your other class.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you just use a `public static` variable to store year entered by use. Now you can use this value throughout the application. To store year in this case there is no need to use an `ArrayList`.

`static` modifier are used for variables that are common to all objects

[Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your class `StudentYear` as follows -

- assign `studentYear` as an instance variable.
- Make a `getter method` in case your instance is not public

  ```
  public class StudentYear 
  {
          private ArrayList<Integer> studentYear;
          public void StudentYear()
          {
                  studentYear = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
                  System.out.println("Please enter the year the student has most recently completed: ");
                  studentYear.add(sc.nextInt());
                  System.out.println(studentYear);
          }
          public ArrayList getStudentYear()
          {
                  return studentYear;
          }
  }
  ```

In another class, just use the getter method of StudentYear class

```
StudentYear obj=new StudentYear();
ArrayList<Integer> studentYear=obj.getStudentYear();
int year=studentYear.get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have implemted these changes and now i'm faced with the errors
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Results.Results(Results.java:11)
 at Main.main(Main.java:21)

Comment: @user3050340 you should provide some code for your Main.java. Then only I can understand the problem